# Kinect face tracking function StartTracking in c++ not give the expected result

Tags: c++, kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm Working with Kinect SDK 1.5 and found some problem when i want to track multiple face.

In my code I first use

```
myFaceTracker->DetectFaces(&sensor, NULL, candidates, &nums)
```

to get the currently detect face, and compare the their position with already tracked faces.

Those are not currently tracked faces will be added to a queue for the tracking in next step.

But when I want to track them using the StartTracking function, it doesn't give expected result.

for example:

```
//Time for us to track those not tracked
RECT rect = queue_face.front();

//Make the region larger than orginal
int length_vertical = rect.bottom - rect.top;
int length_horizontal = rect.right - rect.left;
rect.top    = rect.top - length_vertical * 2;
rect.bottom = rect.bottom + length_vertical * 2;
rect.left   = rect.left - length_horizontal * 2;
rect.right  = rect.right + length_horizontal * 2;

//Use OpenCV to see if it gets right
CvPoint LT = cvPoint(rect.left, rect.top);
CvPoint LB = cvPoint(rect.left, rect.bottom);
CvPoint RT = cvPoint(rect.right, rect.top);
CvPoint RB = cvPoint(rect.right, rect.bottom);

cvLine(_img, LT, LB, cvScalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
cvLine(_img, LB, RB, cvScalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
cvLine(_img, RB, RT, cvScalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
cvLine(_img, RT, LT, cvScalar(0, 255, 0), 2);

//Here turns out to be some problem
result = facetracker->StartTracking(&sensor, &rect, NULL, faceresult);

//Check Result
is_track = SUCCEEDED(result) && SUCCEEDED(faceresult->GetStatus());
queue_face.pop();

....
```

The Code above gives me a totally useless result even if the status says succeed
if we use

```
faceresult->GetFaceRect(rect);
```

it gives us a rect with (0, 0, 0, 0)!

But if we change

```
result = facetracker->StartTracking(&sensor, &rect, NULL, faceresult);
```

to

```
result = facetracker->StartTracking(&sensor, NULL, NULL, faceresult);
```

Now it'll give us something useful, but in this way, its nearly impossible to control whom we want to track.

I also tried to see the input rect to (0, 0, width-1, height-1), but even worse, now it says it can't track anything.

Would anyone give me help?

Thanks a lot.